# How do I build a heart attack gun?

Tags: science-based, weapons

So hearing conspiracy theories about heart attack guns led me to try and come up with an explanation for how to build one.

Is there some combination of heart attack causing factors that could be semi-reliable as a weapon?

Requirements:

- Must be triggered by time or distance
- No projectile or external injury should be seen
- Must be targeted

Maybe some combination of an auditory overload plus targeted microwave laser or similar could do the trick.

"Priming" is allowed, like something transferred by a handshake or spiked in a drink, but solutions without it are preferable.

Comment: Why would a nerve connected to your ear do anything to your heart?

Comment: A weapon doing exactly that was featured in Dan Brown's novel *Digital Fortress*. You may look that up.

Comment: A gun that prints and sends a bill from lawyers or the tax people for a huge sum.  That will cause plenty of heart attacks. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a graphic novel I read in my teens, the antagonist was a killer specialized in leaving no traces after his murders.

His weapon of election was a projectile which:

- could be delivered by a rifle or a blowgun
- melted/splatted on impact with the human body, leaving no sign of impact
- was quickly absorbed by the skin, sort of a lotion
- contained a substance extracted by a tropical worm which caused heart failure within short time from absorption

Note: there are known substances which can achieve the scope of causing the heart to fail. I don't want to share them here because that's a kind of reputation I don't want to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

Would you believe that there already is one?

Users of compressed air blow guns actually have to be [careful not to embolise their bloodstream](https://www.aircontrolindustries.com/jet-black-safety/dangers-of-compressed-air/) when they use the gun close to their skin. It has been known that if you use a high pressure compressed air gun close to your skin the pressure can actually get bubbles of compressed air under your skin, potentially entering the bloodstream.

This is actually dangerous because bubbles of air can effectively block the flow of blood through arteries and veins and can cause symptoms very close to a heart attack. When air gets into the blood stream it's known as an [embolism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embolism) - technically, anything blocking the flow of blood is an embolism but it is important to note here that air in the blood stream is just as effective as other contaminants that can get into the veins and arteries through other means.

Directly related to your question, air embolisms delivered through compresses air would leave very little trace (as it does not have to pierce the skin), and there is no need for a primer to make this happen. The problem of course is the range; you can't give someone even a few metres away from you a heart attack with compressed air. In effect though, if you could wander the streets with a miniaturised but powerful compressed air gun up your sleeve, it's possible you might be able to do a lot of damage.

Comment: The article specifically states that it can enter the bloodstream through breaks in the skin. It cant just enter through undamaged skin.

Answer (score 3):

This is article in Russian about influence of ultra low frequency sound on heart functions - [ВЛИЯНИЕ НИЗКИХ ЧАСТОТ НА СОКРАТИТЕЛЬНУЮ СПОСОБНОСТЬ МИОКАРДА](https://applied-research.ru/ru/article/view?id=10939).

Its possible to make wall of sub woofers powerful enough to make heart attack if anybody close enough. Probably, soundwall like this can be mounted on truck, but its quite hard to make it portable and easy to carry.

[image: soundwall]

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a piece about real-life technology to do this 14 years ago, you can Google it under "Moscow's Remote-Controlled Heart Attacks" which uses electromagnetic radiation:

"His laboratory apparatus uses a modulated beam of radio waves to produce what he terms "disorder of autonomic nervous system," put forward as a possible non-lethal weapon. Makhunin notes that there is no general agreement on how EM waves disrupt nerves - he mentions ion channels similar to those in the plasma paper - but he certainly seems to be seeing the same effects as American researchers. But it need not be a non-lethal weapon. Makhunin also mentions the effects of "change of electrocardiogram" and what he calls "function break of heart muscle"